# Parsing multiple urls with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I started learning Python today and so it is not a surprise that I am struggling with some basics. I am trying to parse data from a school website for a project and I managed to parse the first page. However, there are multiple pages (results are paginated).

I have an idea about how to go about it, ie, run through the urls in a loop since I know the url format but I have no idea how to proceed. I figured it would be better to somehow search for the "next" button and run the function if it is there, if not, then stop function.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.myschoolwebsite.com/1" 
#url2 = "http://www.myschoolwebsite.com/2"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
g_data = soup.find_all('ul', {"class": "searchResults"})

for item in g_data:
    for li in item.findAll('li'):
        for resultnameh2 in li.findAll('h2'):
            for resultname in resultnameh2.findAll('a'):
                print(resultname).text
    for resultAddress in li.findAll('p', {"class": "resultAddress"}):
        print(resultAddress).text.replace('Get directions','').strip()   
    for resultContact in li.findAll('ul', {"class": "resultContact"}):
        for resultContact in li.findAll('a', {"class": "resultMainNumber"}):
            print(resultContact).text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can assume the maximum no. of pages of the directory (if you know pattern of the url). I am assuming the url is of the form `http://base_url/page` Next you can write this:

```
base_url = 'http://www.myschoolwebsite.com'
total_pages = 100

def parse_content(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    g_data = soup.find_all('ul', {"class": "searchResults"})

    for item in g_data:
        for li in item.findAll('li'):
            for resultnameh2 in li.findAll('h2'):
                for resultname in resultnameh2.findAll('a'):
                    print(resultname).text
        for resultAddress in li.findAll('p', {"class": "resultAddress"}):
            print(resultAddress).text.replace('Get directions','').strip()   
        for resultContact in li.findAll('ul', {"class": "resultContact"}):
            for resultContact in li.findAll('a', {"class": "resultMainNumber"}):
                print(resultContact).text

for page in range(1, total_pages):
    response = requests.get(base_url + '/' + str(page))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        break

    parse_content(response)
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran the code but for some reason it is now only outputting resultname.text and omitting all the other fields. Why would it do this?

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Print the url of the page being hit so that you know which is giving only `resultname.text`. Open that url in the browser to see if that is the case. Maybe the html format they are using could be different or there could be no data

Comment: it works fine when I use the code I posted though. I am not sure what the issue could be

Comment: Is this happening for all the pages?

Comment: Yes. I however just tried my old code (posted in my question) and substituted the url to page 2, page 3 etc and it parses the content with no issues.

Comment: Probably some issue with the site or something, ill try figure it out. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would make an array with all the URLs and loop through it, or if there is a clear pattern, write a regex to search for that pattern.